# Google map does not show satellite view

Tags: api, google-maps, satellite

Dear fellow programmers,

can anybody help me with a real headache I encountered while wanting to force a googlemap to show in satellite view? Due to the API docs the code below is exactely what has to be done. Nevertheless it keeps showing up in normal map mode.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem or see the bug that I am not able to identify?

Thanks for reading and your efforts.

PHP:

```
<?php if($gmapaddress!=""){ ?>
    <div class="gmap"><div id="gmap_inner"></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=es"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $template_uri;?>/js/jquery.gmap.js"></script> 
    <script> 
          jQuery(window).load(function(){
              //set google map with marker
              jQuery("#gmap_inner").gMap({
                  markers: [{
                      address: '<?php echo $gmapaddress; ?>'<?php if($gmapinfo!="") {?>,
                      html: '<?php echo $gmapinfo; ?>' <?php } ?>                         
                    }],  
                  zoom: <?php echo $gmapzoom;?>,
                  mapOptions: [{mapTypeID: "satellite"}] 
              });
          });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

generated HTML/javascript:

```
<div class="gmap"><div id="gmap_inner"></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=es"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/csmlu/wp-content/themes/zeitgeist/js/jquery.gmap.js"></script> 
<script> 
      jQuery(window).load(function(){
          //set google map with marker
          jQuery("#gmap_inner").gMap({
              markers: [{
                  address: '-40.297357°,-73.084091°'                          
                }],  
              zoom: 18,
              mapOptions: [{mapTypeId: "satellite"}] 
          });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive.  The MapTypeId option has a lower case "d":

```
mapOptions: [{mapTypeID: "satellite"}]
```

should be:

```
mapOptions: [{mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE}]
```

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

UPDATE: the plugin you are using is still using the [deprecated (and turned off) Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), its syntax and options are different, set the maptype property to G_SATELLITE_MAP there is no mapOptions property.

```
<script> 
      jQuery(window).load(function(){
          //set google map with marker
          jQuery("#gmap_inner").gMap({
              markers: [{
                  address: '-40.297357,-73.084091'
                }],
              zoom: 18,
              maptype: G_SATELLITE_MAP
          });
      });
</script>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_JQuery_gmap.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally missed this. Strange enough even with the correction it does not work. I am developing locally. Still I do not see how this could probably interfere?

Comment: What does the HTML generated by the PHP look like? Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=es"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/csmlu/wp-content/themes/zeitgeist/js/jquery.gmap.js"></script> 
    <script> 
          jQuery(window).load(function(){
              //set google map with marker
              jQuery("#gmap_inner").gMap({
                  markers: [{
       address: '-40.297357°,-73.084091°'        
     }],  
                  zoom: 18,
      mapOptions: [{mapTypeId: "satellite"}] 
              });
          });
    </script>`

Comment: This is what the php renders. The console keeps perfectely quiet. I have never ever encountered that. I am stunned.

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question with the HTML (rather than attempting to post it as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, still it is not quite clear why my call in the code above does actually not do what it is supposed to do. A workaround I just found is to look up the gmaps.js corefile and change the maptypeID in there from ROADMAPS to SATELLITE. In case anyone comes across the same issue this might be of help.